# Как синтаксически правильно построить фразу?

Tags: синтаксис

"По поводу последнего абзаца я собираюсь написать..."

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря: **По поводу кого-чего**. в зн. предлога. 1. Относительно кого-, чего-л. **Решение по поводу** премьерного фильма. Высказаться **по поводу результатов** голосования.

Пример законченной фразы: Как раз **по поводу последнего абзаца** я и собираюсь написать.

**Примечание.** Желательно приводить полный текст предложения, чтобы оценить его корректность, если вопрос  именно о фразе (не про отдельное словосочетание).

Answer (score 0):

По поводу... - это официальный стиль. Если вы используете эту фразу в разговорной речи, то можно написать "про последний абзац, или о последнем абзаце..."